# Fastest method to encode characters beyond the ASCII range to respective %uxxxx in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, encode

In Javascript, what would be fastest method to encode unicode characters outside ASCII range to their respective %uxxxx. I need to use this method to encode hundreds of KBs of data (number of unicode characters outside ASCII range within this data is fairly low). I have been using 'escape' currently, but that's very slow given that it also encodes many other characters than just non-ASCII.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "unicode characters" but it's a misconception at best. Do you mean characters outside the ASCII range (0-127)? (And note that ASCII is a subset of Unicode...).

Comment: Sorry, I meant characters outside ASCII.

Comment: Changed question as suggested by @dda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`escape` is native code. Nothing you could code in JS could beat that...

Comment: `escape` doesn't necessarily do `%uxxxx`, for example: `escape("ö");
//"%F6"`